# Allow Angular XSS Attack

Tags: angular, xss, angular7

I want to create an example of xss attack, with angular 7, for teaching purposes.

```
<div class="container mt-3">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let message of messages">{{message}}</li>
            <li *ngFor="let message of messages" [innerHTML]="message"></li>
            <li *ngFor="let message of messages" [innerHTML]="message | keepHtml"></li>
        </ul>
        <ng-container *ngIf="messages.length === 0">No messages</ng-container>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
        <hr/>
        <label>New Message</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="model.message" name="message"></textarea>
        <button class="btn btn-success mt-2" (click)="submit()">Send Message</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({ name: 'keepHtml', pure: false })
export class EscapeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {
    constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    }

    transform(content) {
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(content);
    }
}
```

I want to send message `<script>alert('1');</script>` and let the alert run

Comment: Probably not the best approach for teaching if you have to do extra work to make the attack possible. I would use an example where it is easy to get it wrong.

Comment: Check this out https://angular.io/guide/security

Comment: have you tried `bypassSecurityTrustScript` ?

Comment: I get this error with bypassSecurityTrustScript: "Required a safe HTML, got a Script"

Comment: @Henry I want to make them see the actual problem and the actual solution from angular